# Froala <ul> list-item not appearing

Tags: angular6, editor, froala

Encountering strange issue in Froala,

This is how my Froala, editor looks like when un-ordered list is selected, but it's not appearing in the text-input.

[image]

This is how DOM looks like at this moment, indication presence of **ul** item.

[image]

But when I remove the **overflow**, property from **fr-wrapper** class inside froala-editor, then I can see the **list item dot** as follows.

[image]

Here is the overflow, property, removing overflow property below is doing manipulation on internal css of **froala**, I don't want to this.

[image]

I don't know why froala is not behaving in intended manner,
**Expected behaviour** should be like this as soon as user selects, the **ul** list item, without even touching or manipulating any **internal css** prop. like overflow etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add below lines in your css file. this will render the list style type that you have applied to the list items while editing the content through froala editor.

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: inherit;
}

ol li {
  list-style-type: inherit;
}
```